# API to get Top Docker Hub images?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I would like to know is there an API to get the Top Docker Hub images?

Like what we can get when we open https://hub.docker.com/explore/

I have checked:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.28/# and 
https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/

But did not find what I want.

Comment: Did you read the API docs? https://docs.docker.com/v1.4/reference/api/docker-io_api/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [`https://hub.docker.com/explore/`](https://hub.docker.com/explore/), the following API is called :

https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/?page=1&page_size=15

The default filter is by descending pull count, it will give you the following response :

```json
{
    "count": 139,
    "next": "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/?page=1&page_size=15",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [{
        "user": "library",
        "name": "nginx",
        "namespace": "library",
        "repository_type": "image",
        "status": 1,
        "description": "Official build of Nginx.",
        "is_private": false,
        "is_automated": false,
        "can_edit": false,
        "star_count": 5777,
        "pull_count": 618674944,
        "last_updated": "2017-04-06T16:35:19.178373Z",
        "build_on_cloud": null
    },
    ...
    ...
   ]
}
```

So the following will give your the top 100 docker images pulled on docker hub :

https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/?page=1&page_size=100

The `page_size` has a maximum size of 100 (so 100 per page) and `count` is the maximum count this endpoint can give (for all pages).

For instance with `curl` and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON parser :

```bash
curl -s "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/?page=1&page_size=100" | \
    jq '.results'
```

---

Now there is an internal API from https://store.docker.com to query images either from the store or from dockerhub. The most popular ones from dockerhub can be retrieved with :

https://store.docker.com/api/content/v1/products/search?page_size=100&q=%2B&source=community&type=image%2Cbundle

Request result has a `popularity` numeric field. To get the images filtered by descending popularity:

```bash
curl -s "https://store.docker.com/api/content/v1/products/search?page_size=100&q=%2B&source=community&type=image%2Cbundle" | \
    jq '.summaries | sort_by(-.popularity)'
```

Comment: Where can I find the full API reference of Docker Hub?  I only find APIs from Docker Engine and Docker Registry

Comment: this is v1: https://docs.docker.com/v1.4/reference/api/docker-io_api/

Comment: I didn't find it either, I've opened an issue [there](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/2800) to know why this reference doesn't exist at https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker-io_api/